# Is it possible to separate "\t" to char '\' + 't'

Tags: javascript, string, escaping, char

I have got string containing windows path to file. It looks something like this:

```
var path = 'c:\test\old\new\ring.txt';
```

Os and browser gave it to me. So I can not change it by manually writing '\' in front of every '\'. Every '\' is just '\,' regular win path delimiter. Problem arises if '\' is followed by t, r, n.

Then it becomes white space. But if I pass that as function parameter string is automatically changed in way that all \ are gone!

So, is there a way to somehow separate '\t' '\n' '\r'... to '\' + char?

If not, is is possible to somehow escape '\' so that they remain '\'? Like \ and not to become tab, new line, etc

edit:
Maybe I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escape the backslash by doubling it: `c:\\test\\etc`.

Answer (score 4):

```
var path = 'c:\\test\\old\\new\\ring.txt';
```

Answer (score 4):

The backslash *is* the escape character, so you are escaping the t, n, o, and r. You need to escape the backslash. You can do that like this:

```
var path = 'c:\\test\\old\\new\\ring.txt';
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to use backslashes, escape them: `'C:\\whatever'`

If the path is actually meant to be used: Use forward slashes. While windows *displays* backslashes, it *accepts* forward slashes, too.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was my mistake.
OS already gave me escaped backslashes '\' path! 
I was getting undefined from mu function because of this pointing to html object and not js object with function.

My bad :(