# Why do I need to replace \n with \n?

Tags: javascript, replace, split

I have a line of data like this:

`1•#00DDDD•deeppink•1•100•true•25•100•Random\nTopics•1,2,3,0•false`
in a text file.

Specifically, for my "problem", I am using `Random\nTopics` as a piece of text data, and I then search for '\n', and split the message up into two lines based on the placement of '\n'.

It is stored in blockObj.msg, and I search for it using `blockObj.msg.split('\n')`, but I kept getting an array of 1 (no splits).  I thought I was doing something fundamentally wrong and spent over an hour troubleshooting, until on a whim, I tried

`blockObj.msg = blockObj.msg.replace(/\\n/g, "\n")`

and that seemed to solve the problem.  Any ideas as to why this is needed?  My solution works, but I am clueless as to why, and would like to understand better so I don't need to spend so long searching for an answer as bizarre as this.

I have a similar error when reading "text" from an input text field.  If I type a '\n' in the box, the split will not find it, but using a replace works (the replace seems pointless, but apparently isn't...)

`obj.msg = document.getElementById('textTextField').value.replace(/\\n/g, "\n")`

Sorry if this is jumbled, long time user of reading for solutions, first time posting a question. Thank you for your time and patience!

P.S. If possible... is there a way to do the opposite?  Replace a real "\n" with a fake "\n"? (I would like to have my dynamically generated data file to have a "\n" instead of a new line)

Comment: You have `\n` *as text*. However the escape sequence `\n` when used *in a string literal* signifies a newline. Which the literal text of "backslash followed by the letter **n**" is not. You don't need to replace it, you just have to split by the sequence "backslash followed by the letter **n**"  which in a string literal is expressed as `\\n`  - the backslash is escaped to make it a literal backslash.

Comment: Basically you can say, this boils down to the difference between _data_, and _code_.

Comment: [JavaScript backslash (\) in variables is causing an error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3903488) | [How can I use backslashes (\) in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10041998) | [Escaping backslash in string - javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8618374) | [Escape new lines with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25921319) | [How to escape backslashes from a string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63056335) | [Is it possible to separate "\t" to char '\' + 't'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7649372) |

Answer (score 3):

> It is stored in blockObj.msg, and I search for it using `blockObj.msg.split('\n')`,

In a JavaScript string literal, `\n` is an escape sequence representing a new line, so you are splitting the data on new lines.

The data you have **doesn't** have new lines in it though. It has slash characters followed by n characters. They are data, not escape sequences.

Your call to replace (`blockObj.msg = blockObj.msg.replace(/\\n/g, "\n")`) works around this by replacing the slashes and ns with new lines.

That's an overcomplicated approach though. You can match the characters you have directly. `blockObj.msg.split('\\n')`

Comment: I... feel like vomiting a little, but this seems to make sense.
Honestly, I probably should have  mentioned that I have very little idea of what I'm doing with .replace, and I have been just using it with copy/paste as needed.  I always wondered why it had so many slashes... but that explains one of the slashes (and it solves my problem).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in your text file

`1•#00DDDD•deeppink•1•100•true•25•100•Random\nTopics•1,2,3,0•false`

means that there are characters which are `\` and `n` thats how they are stored, but to insert a `new line character` by replacement, you are then searching for the `\` and the `n` character pair.

```js
obj.msg = document.getElementById('textTextField').value.replace(/\\n/g, "\n")
```

when you do the `replace(/\\n/g, "\n")`

you are searching for `\\n` this is the escaped version of the string, meaing that the replace must find all strings that are `\n` but to search for that you need to escape it first into `\\n`

### EDIT

`/\\n/g` is the regex string.....  `\n` is the value... so `/\REGEXSTUFFHERE/g`  the last `/`  is followed by regex flags, so `g` in `/g` would be global search

[regex resources](https://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_regexp.asp)

[test regex online](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: I suck at using replace, and have been copying and pasting as needed.  I always thought the `replace(/\` part was standard, and that i was just using `\n` afterwards.  Your explanation really helped.  Thanks.